# Which cells from a list are in a string?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of IDs in a column and I want to compare them against semi-colon separated strings and determine which ID is part of it.

[image: Data]

I have the following code, which partially works:

```
Function SeparatedListContains(ByVal str As String, ByVal v As Range, _
Optional ByVal delimiter As String = ";") As String

Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim splitStr() As String

splitStr = Split(str, delimiter)
SeparatedListContains = False
For i = LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr)
    For Each cell In v
        If splitStr(i) = cell Then
            SeparatedListContains = cell
        End If
    Next cell
Next i
End Function
```

The code only compares the first item in the separated string and doesn't go to the next item in the separated string if the first one isn't a match from the IDs.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "fun" problem that bites every single one of us.

Look closely at your data:

[image: OP's data]

The delimiter isn't `;`, it's `;WHITESPACE`.

By splitting on `;`, the values you get in the first index look like this:

- `A123`
- `C123`
- `C456`

But the data in the next index looks like this:

- `_C123`
- `_A456`
- `_D789`

Where `_` represents a space. And `Debug.Print "C123" = " C123"` will print `False`.

The solution is therefore to `Trim` the values before you compare them - and then just bail out:

```
SeparatedListContains = vbNullString
For i = LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr)    
    For Each cell In v
        Dim value As Variant
        value = cell.value
        If Not IsError(value) Then
            If Trim$(splitStr(i)) = Trim$(value) Then
                SeparatedListContains = Trim$(value)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Trimming the `value` might seem excessive, but my experience is that if you don't trim it now, you'll be trimming it later anyway.

By bailing out immediately with `Exit Function`, you avoid unnecessary iterations.

By defaulting to `vbNullString` instead of `False` (`"False"` actually), we return *nothing* when we find *nothing*. If this function is used as a UDF, I would recomment returning a `Variant` instead, and default to an actual error value, e.g. `CVErr(xlNA)` - that way you leverage Excel's own failing-function mechanism.

The `IsError` check is because you don't want to throw a runtime error if the given `Range` contains, say, a `#REF!` error: as a UDF that makes Excel swallow the error and return `#VALUE!` - but as a VBA function called from VBA code, that means <s>an explosion</s> runtime error 13 "type mismatch", when VBA tries to compare a string to an error value.

Comment: @YowE3K if the problem is what I think it is, it looks like an Excel 2016 bug - can't repro with Excel 2010.

Comment: rather than returning just the first match, how can a list be added to return all matches per string?

Comment: @U.Ch you could concatenate the results as you go: `SeparatedListContains = SeparatedListContains & ";" & Trim$(value)`

Comment: Thank you once again! But I think, I may be wrong, it exits the function after first match. I am getting ";FIRST MATCH" now.

Comment: that's `Exit Function` bailing out

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SeparatedListContains = False
```

do

```
SeparatedListContains = splitStr(LBound(splitStr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using native functions as well.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&A2&";"," "&TRIM(C2)&";",1)),A2,FALSE)`